# Why can't I access files in the same directory as my notebook in jupyterLab hosted on aws emr?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, jupyter-lab

I am newbie to aws, I launched an emr-cluster and intend to run JupyterLab on top of it for an analytic Spark project.
In order to access S3, I need my IAM access credentials  which resides in dl.cfg file in the same directory as the notebook ( prototyping.ipynb), I got an error telling dl.cfg doesn't exist.

[image: here is a screenshot of further description.]

Have anyone experienced such situation ? Is the dl.cfg file in a wrong directory?
I even tried the full S3 URI and it didn’t work.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `os.getcwd()` to confirm your current directiry

Comment: Could you try EMR release label 5.29?

Comment: @ParagChaudhari I see this comment on all the topics on EMR not being able to import other notebooks, other scripts from the same directory. Something seems to be fundamentally broken there. We are on what 5.3x version and I still can't import other notebooks...